What could this lump on my cat be?

On my cats neck face area.....

It could be reason to get the cat to a vet rather than ask the internet.

@keshlam Not only that, but the image quality is so bad I can't properly tell much about it.

Short answer: it's a wound. Whether this was caused by a fight or a pimple or insect bite or any of the countless other possibilities is impossible to tell.
It looks like the cat licked it, which is 100% normal and natural behavior. The cat keeps dirt and hair out of the wound by licking. But it can become more of a problem if the rough tongue irritates the skin and makes the wound bigger.
You should regularly check the wound until it's healed.

If you notice pus or anything but a clear, yellowish liquid coming from it, go to a vet.
If the color changes to anything but a reddish pink (or normal skin color when it's healed), go to a vet.
If the wound suddenly becomes bigger or drastically changes in any other aspect, go to a vet quickly.
If you notice that the wound causes your cat obvious pain even when you don't touch it or if your cat suddenly behaves very different (like sleeping or hiding more than usual, not eating, being aggressive towards you, seeming sluggish and confused), immediately go to a vet as a medical emergency!

If none of the above happens, it's probably no big deal. You should not apply any cream or medication (topical or internal) without checking with your vet first because cats can be poisoned by things that are safe for us. From my experience any wounds on cats take a long time to heal, because they lick or scratch them open repeatedly. You can expect this to take at least several weeks, probably more than a month.

If the cat tolerates it, you can also smell the wound. Cats generally don't have strong body odor, so if there is an infection that isn't visible, you might still be able to detect it by scent.
Also, keep an eye out for changes in behavior, especially unusual fatigue or increased preference for hidden resting places.

This is probably not just a wound, and it will not likely just heal and go away on its own. It cannot be diagnosed over the internet and needs to be evaluated by a vet.
